# Broadcasting the time, through signalr hub

Tags: asp.net, timer, signalr

I am self-hosting a signalR hub, using the OWIN stuff mentioned in the signalR wiki.

Every 20 seconds, I would like it to broadcast the current time, to all members in the 'clock' group.
I have a method in my hub, called UpdateClock, that handles the broadcast.

But, to get this timer to run, and actually broadcast, what is the "smartest" way to do this?

The way I see it, I need a timer in the service that hosts the hub, and have it create a connection to the hub and invoke the command. It just seems like a lot of work, for very little functionality. Is it possible to do this, directly in the hub class, so I don't have to create a connection first?

This is what I have done, so far and I would like it to be more simple:

```
var signalConnection = new HubConnection(_signalREndPoint);
var hubProxy = signalConnection.CreateHubProxy(_signalRHubName);
signalConnection.Start().Wait();
hubProxy.Invoke(UpdateClock);
signalConnection.Stop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the context of the Hub and invoke client methods on your own service:

```
while (conditionToRun)
{
     Thread.Sleep(WaitForInSeconds * 1000);
     var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<YourHubName>();
     context.Clients.Group("clockGroupName").updateClock(DateTime.UtcNow);
}
```

This is how I do it when I need to broadcast server side events to the clients.